# openvpn client mess up port forwarding

Tags: ssh, vpn, openvpn, port-forwarding

I have a Fedora 25 box at home running behind my ISP router. I have set up the router to port forward SSH to the Fedora box which would allow me to ssh from outside.

Now I'm trying to set up OpenVPN client on the Fedora box to connect to my VPN provider. To my surprise, whenever the VPN connection is made, I cannot connect to it from outside through the port forwarding. I could, however, ssh to it using its LAN IP when at home.

Can anyone explain what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't mess with the port forwarding; the issue is related to routing. The OpenVPN client may introduce a new default route to `0.0.0.0` (any IP) that replaces the routing through your LAN router. However, the LAN is on the same subnet: the connection is made on layer 2, not through the default gateway.